# Unexplainable whitespace?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I'm just coding something simple, but there seems to be an unexplainable whitespace in my result...
And I can't seem to lose it!

To be clear: I mean the 'line' between the purple header and the white nav-attribute.

I tried getting rid of the tabs and spaces in my code, but it did not help.

Here's a simple fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LNhK5/

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <header>
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
    </header>

    <nav id="mainMenu">
        <ul>
            <li>Nieuwsoverzicht</li>
            <li>Trending</li>
            <li>Lokaal nieuws</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#wrapper{
    width:100%; 

    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

header{
    background-color:#835497;

    height:70px;
    width:100%;

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.logo{
    height:80%;

    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

nav{
    background-color:#ffffff;

    height:45px;
    width:100%;

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav#mainMenu ul li{
    font-family:'source_sans_proregular';
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#c2c2c2;

    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
```

Is it something I'm overlooking, or did I just make a typo-error?

Comment: Which space are we talking about?

Comment: Right click on the whitespace, select "inspect element".

Comment: Because your <ul> have not reseted margin to 0

Comment: The space between the header and the nav attribute :)
The weird thing is, when trying 'inspect element', there doesn't seem to be anything there, no margin, no attribute..

Comment: @Falcon: Thanks, that was it! But why doesn't it show in 'expect element'?

Comment: @Lisa It sure did, but you just haven't noticed :)

Comment: as @mobabur94 stated in his answer.. the UL has margins (and padding).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the whitespace you are talking about is due to the `ul` ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQLzx)

Try setting the margin to zero:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: You should also STRONGLY consider using a CSS reset.  These allow you to remove browser-specific default CSS styles so that you are working with more of a blank canvas so to speak.

Comment: Yeah, those are awesome. I like [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: It's a shame, that developers of browsers couldn't do that "normalized". I don't get why there are some default styles.

Comment: Thanks! I actually was looking for that but didn't remember it's name :)

Answer (score 0):

Your list ul has a default margin. Remove it with:

```
#mainMenu ul{
    margin-top:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LNhK5/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace you are seeing is the result of a **collapsing margin** between the `ul` element and the `header` element.

If you add `overflow: auto` to the `nav` element, it will contain any margins of the child elements, in this case, the `ul` element.

You can control the top margin of `ul` by explictly setting the top margin value to zero to 
over-ride the default value.

Answer (score 0):

There is 0 margin and padding in your LI but not in UL. Therefore the default padding and margin of a UL still exist. To fix, please add this style:

```
 nav#mainMenu ul{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain some of the contents. If you do explain this (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!